# Can you consider named and annonymous pipes as asynchronous?

Tags: pipe, ipc

Title says it all. Are pipes working in a non-blocking fashion? Does anyone have scientific sources to answer my question? I am not able to really judge it. Overall, ever source which is not on the first 3 google pages would help me :)

Greetings

Comment: What operating system?  And in any case on Unix it depends on whether you open the pipe in nonblocking mode or not.  This is generally true: devices aren't inherently blocking or non-blocking, it's the I/O calls that have that characteristic.  Trivially: read the Unix man page for pipe(2).  Note the O_NONBLOCK flag.

Comment: Hey Iggi, im on raspbian and totally forgot that the man pages are a thing. Shouldve read them before asking here :D Also your answer helped me a lot, thank you!